# What's the connection between typeface "Terminal" and "@Terminal" on Windows?

Tags: winapi, fonts, console, typography

```
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
    lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    auto proc = [](const LOGFONT *lpelfe, const TEXTMETRIC *lpntme,
        DWORD FontType, LPARAM lParam) {
        s_faceNames_.push_back(lpelfe->lfFaceName);
        return 1;
    };
    EnumFontFamiliesEx(hdc, &lf, proc, NULL, 0);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

Then output the result facenames:

```
[21:09:16:324]  index = 0, facename: Terminal, lfweigt: 400, italic: false fullname:Terminal, charset:255   (simpletest.cpp:71:SimpleTest::testFontEnum)
[21:09:16:324]  index = 1, facename: @Terminal, lfweigt: 400, italic: false fullname:@Terminal, charset:134 (simpletest.cpp:71:SimpleTest::testFontEnum)
```

To draw hello world with this two font:

```
HFONT CreateFont(const std::wstring& fontName, int fontSize, int* charset = NULL) 
{
    LOGFONT lf;
    memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(lf));
    StringCchCopy(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, fontName.c_str());
    if (charset) {
        lf.lfCharSet = *charset;
    } else {
        lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    }

    auto proc = [](const LOGFONT *lpelfe, const TEXTMETRIC *lpntme,
        DWORD FontType, LPARAM lParam) {
        LPENUMLOGFONTEX fontEx = (LPENUMLOGFONTEX)(lpelfe);
        PLOGFONT ret = (PLOGFONT)(lParam);
        *ret = fontEx->elfLogFont;
        return 0;
    };
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    EnumFontFamiliesEx(dc, &lf, proc, (LPARAM)&lf, 0);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    lf.lfWidth = 0;
    lf.lfHeight = -std::abs(fontSize);
    if (charset) {
        *charset = lf.lfCharSet;
    }
    return CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
}
```

wm_paint handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    {
        int charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
        HFONT hf = CreateFont(L"Terminal", 12, &charset);
        HFONT hOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hf);
        StringCchPrintf(buff, MAX_PATH, L"hello, world charset: %d", charset);
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, buff, wcslen(buff));
        SelectObject(hdc, hOld);
    }
    {
        int charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
        HFONT hf = CreateFont(L"@Terminal", 12, &charset);
        HFONT hOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hf);
        StringCchPrintf(buff, MAX_PATH, L"hello, world charset: %d", charset);
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, buff, wcslen(buff));
        SelectObject(hdc, hOld);
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

result:
[image: terminal_font_render_result]

Text rendered are resemble, except the later have wider char-width, so is there any naming convertion or link between these typeface/font, or the first is bitmap font and the later is vector font?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/19/10331400.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void drawText(HDC hdc, int startx1, const std::wstring& fontName, const std::wstring& text)
{
    int degree = 270;
    int startx2 = startx1 + 200;
    int starty = 200;
    MoveToEx(hdc, startx1, 0, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, startx1, 700);
    MoveToEx(hdc, startx2, 0, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, startx2, 700);

    WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    {
        {
            int charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
            HFONT hf = CreateFont(fontName.c_str(), 12, degree, &charset);
            FASSERT(hf);
            HFONT hOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hf);
            auto str1 = fontName + text;
            StringCchPrintf(buff, MAX_PATH, str1.c_str(), charset);
            TextOut(hdc, startx1, starty, buff, wcslen(buff));
            SelectObject(hdc, hOld);
        }
            {
                std::wstring fontName2 = L"@" + fontName;
                int charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
                HFONT hf = CreateFont(fontName2.c_str(), 12, degree, &charset);
                FASSERT(hf);
                auto str2 = fontName2.c_str() + text;
                HFONT hOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hf);
                StringCchPrintf(buff, MAX_PATH, str2.c_str(), charset);
                TextOut(hdc, startx2, starty, buff, wcslen(buff));
                SelectObject(hdc, hOld);
            }
    }
}
```

wm_paint handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    drawText(hdc, 200, L"SimSun", L"我跟你什么仇什么怨？");
    drawText(hdc, 600, L"Termainl", L"What hatred, what emity");
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

result:
[image]

conclusion:
@simsun is vertical font, which support vertical text; simsun is not vertical font, which does not support vertical text.

So simsun merely rotate the text, did not do any transformation, and @simsun did.